# POST httpRequest/AJAX to external API in Sharepoint Online

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, ibm-cloud, sharepoint-online, visual-recognition

**Scenery**

I trying make an a call to an service in IBM Cloud and I have send an file.
This request must be done in Sharepoint Online using JavaScript. In the request a file will be sent.
**Problem**

I have problem with cross domain(Sharepoint side) and bad request(IBM side) in Sharepoint Online. I tried sereval ways.

**Attempts**

*To solve Cross domain problem:*

```
$.ajax({
    url: "../_api/SP.WebProxy.invoke",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(
        {
            "requestInfo": {
                "__metadata": { "type": "SP.WebRequestInfo" },
                "Url": "https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api/v3/classify?api_key={API-KEY}&version=2016-05-20",
                "Method": "POST",
                "Headers": {
                    "results": [{
                        "__metadata": { "type": "SP.KeyValue" }, 
                        "Key": "Accept",
                        "Value": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                        "ValueType": "Edm.String"
                    }, {
                        "__metadata": { "type": "SP.KeyValue" },
                        "Key": "Content-Type",
                        "Value": "application/json",
                        "ValueType": "Edm.String"
                    }]
                }
                ,
                "Body": JSON.stringify({ "files":[ { "name":"imagem.png","content": image } ]})//Problem here
            }
        }),
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    success: function (data) {
        alert("Sucesso");
        console.log(data.d.Invoke.StatusCode);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data.d.Invoke.Body));
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert("Falha");
        console.log(arguments[2]);
    }
});
```

This way the problem Cross domain(Sharepoint) is solved, but I receive Bad request(IBM API). The model resquest send file is show bellow.

```
"Body": JSON.stringify({ "files":[ { "name":"imagem.png","content": image } ]})
```

*To solve Bad request problem:*

```
function CORS() {
var data = new FormData();
data.append("imagemTeste", $("#imagem")[0].files[0]);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api/v3/classify?api_key={API-KEY}&version=2016-05-20');
xhr.onload = function (e) {
    var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
    console.log(data);
}    
xhr.send(data);

}
```

Here the problem Bad request is solved(IBM API), but I get cross domain error(Sharepoint).

I'm out of ideas to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to invoke the API from a server. For example, you can use Cloud Functions to call this API. Any other server-side environment should work. Hope this helps.